# JPA/Hibernate: delete entity referenced by @OneToOne immutable entity not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a main table `Lot` and a database view `LotValues` (which contains some calculated fields...).
The view `LotValues` has the same `id` of `Lot`.

This is the main entity `Lot`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FDE_LOT")
public class Lot {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "lot", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private LotValues lotValues;

}
```

This is the database view `LotValues`, so I defined it as `@Immutable` entity:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "FDE_LOT_VALUES")
public class LotValues {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Lot lot;

    private Double size;

}
```

When I call the `lotRepository.delete(id)`, Hibernate performs two SELECT queries on Lot entity and on LotValues entity, but the DELETE query is not executed.

If I remove the `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "lot", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` inthe main entity `Lot`, the DELETE query is executed.

Why this? Maybe the definition of the primary key of the @Immutable entity is wrong?

Comment: did you tryusing `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in your oneToOne mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Solved setting to null the references

```
LotValues lotValues = lotValuesRepository.findOne(id);
lotValues.setLot(null);

Lot lot = lotRepository.findOne(id);
lot.setLotValues(null);

lotRepository.delete(id);
```